# Eclipse/RAP/GEF Indigo to Eclipse/RAP/GEF Kepler

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-rap

I am not an Eclipse/RAP developer, but over a year ago I was tasked with getting a particular application to run.  The development environment was Eclipse/RAP using Java.  The application was already almost done -- I just needed to make a few changes to get it to work the way we wanted it to work.  I made the changes, stuck it into the Jboss app, and it worked.  I saved away my source code.

Since then they upgraded my PC, so I no longer have access to my old development environment.  We need to move the RAP application to another server, and for some reason it has quit working.  Either I don't understand why it ever worked or I don't understand why it doesn't work -- it's all a bit baffling.

So now I'm trying to get this thing working again.

The basic problem I haven't been able to resolve is dependencies.  Eclipse reports that the following three bundles can't be found:

org.eclipse.rap.draw2d
org.eclipse.rap.zest.core
org.eclipse.rap.zest.layouts

All three should be in the GEF package.

I have tried installing Eclipse Indigo.  When I do that, Eclipse can't find GEF to install it, even though it's given the same URL as I give to Kepler.  I've installed Eclipse Kepler.  I can install GEF, but while Eclipse reports a valid install, and reports that it is installed, I'm still seeing the same missing dependencies.

Any ideas?  It's baffled an Eclipse developer here, but then we don't really use RAP except for this one application.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Sean.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dependency-related issue, and has nothing to do with RAP. Nevertheless, be careful that the notion of GEF has changed a bit. GEF4 includes: GEF, Zest, Draw2D. Rather than installing the whole thing, I suggest you download your dependencies (i.e. go to GIT and pull the GEF4 project), and then include those projects (or build them as JARs) and include them to be available at **runtime**, and of course as dependencies.